# Getting Entity Behind Selected Row From DataGridView with Linq To Sql

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, datagridview

What is a graceful/proper way to retrieve the Linq entity behind the selected row of a DataGridView?
I am populating my DataGridView like this in the form Load event:

```
this.Database = new MyAppDataContext();
var userList = from c in this.Database.Users
                       orderby c.LastName
                       select c;
        this.gridUserList.DataSource = userList;
```

Then, in the DoubleClick event of the form I am doing this:

```
        int userPK = Convert.ToInt32(this.gridUserList.CurrentRow.Cells["colUserPK"].Value);
        var user = (from c in this.Database.Users 
                    where c.UserPK == userPK select c).First() ;
        //Do something with user object
```

It seems like there should be a more elegant way of getting the user row that was double-clicked on.

Comment: What is your question? Are you getting an exception?  What do you want to make with the user object? Share more information with us please.

Comment: The issue that I see is that I'm not able to get to the selected user object in a clean, strongly typed, object oriented fashion. One theoretically improved way of doing this would be to have a UserList property on the form that would be the Linq query object. i.e., "this.UserList = from c in this.Database.Users....." etc, and set the grid DataSource to this.UserList. Then in the DoubleClick event, be able to say "var User = UserList.CurrentEntity" or "var User = UserList.SelectedEntity" or something like that. Anyway, I'm new to Linq, still learning and researching, and looking for opinions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the best option I have found:

```
var selectedUser = (User)this.gridUserList.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem;
```

Another option if you are using a BindingSource is:

```
var selectedUser = (User)this.userBindingSource.Current;
```

Answer (score 1):

I have bind `MyDataSourceTable` to `dataGridView1`. The C# code looks like this:

```
List<MyDataSourceItem> MyDataSourceTable;
bs = new BindingSource();
bs.DataSource = MyDataSourceTable;
dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
```

When the user of my program select a row on `dataGridView1`, we know what row since we have the row index. Using the Answer in the above posting, the corresponding entry in the data source is referenced by just one single line of code:

```
private void dataGridView1_CurrentCellChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count <= 0) return; // this line prevents exception
    MyDataSourceItem mdsi = (MyDataSourceItem)this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem; // Alvin S
    // mdsi now reference the corresponding object on the list
    .
    .
}
```

To safeguard exception being thrown on `null` object, an `if` clause is added. Alvin S's answer is very direct and sccinct. It is valuable.